# sql query to add a coloumn based on 2 other coloumns sequel server

Tags: sql-server, sum, multiple-columns

I dont believe this has been answered although variations may have

Headings are  DATE, ACCOUNT, CODE, CONSIDERATION

The database has multiple DATE and there are several entries of each DATE. 
For each DATE there is a CODE (ABC,DEF etc). There are multiple entries of the same CODE for the same DATE as well.  There are also multiple ACCOUNT for each DATE and there could be the same  ACCOUNT many times across the same date. 
The CONSIDERATION coloumn is the one I want to sum per DATE per ACCOUNT per CODE.

For example,  CODE   (ABC) may  appear several times in the same date, ACCOUNT 12345 may also appear several times in the same date.

The output would have several dates for the same day, each CODE showing only once for  each DATE, (the same account could appear many times in a given date but each time with a different code)  , with the CONSIDERATION being summed up for each.

```
DATE       |    ACCOUNT     |   CODE            |   CONSIDERATION |
01-01-2017 |    111         |      ABC          |       7         |
01-01-2017 |    111         |      ABC          |       6         |
01-01-2017 |    111         |      DEF          |       12        |
01-01-2017 |    222         |      ABC          |       12        |  
01-01-2017 |    222         |      DEF          |       50        |
01-01-2017 |    333         |      GHI          |       8         |
01-01-2017 |    333         |      GHI          |       19        |

02-01-2017 |    111         |      ABC          |       15        | 
02-01-2017 |    222         |      ABC          |       20        |
02-01-2017 |    111         |      ABC          |       10        |
02-01-2017 |    111         |      DEF          |       8         |
02-01-2017 |    222         |      DEF          |       11        |
02-01-2017 |    222         |      LMN          |       8         |
02-01-2017 |    222         |      LMN          |       27        |
```

OUTPUT

```
DATE       |    ACCOUNT     |   CODE            |   CONSIDERATION
01-01-2017 |    111         |      ABC          |       13
01-01-2017 |    111         |      DEF          |       12
01-01-2017 |    222         |      ABC          |       12
01-01-2017 |    222         |      DEF          |       50
01-01-2017 |    333         |      GHI          |       27

02-02-2017 |    111         |      ABC          |       25
02-02-2017 |    111         |      DEF          |       8
02-02-2017 |    222         |      ABC          |       20
02-02-2017 |    222         |      DEF          |       11
02-02-2017 |    222         |      LMN          |       35
```

Comment: A sample dataset and expected output can make your question more clearly....

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple `group by`

```
SELECT  [DATE],
       ACCOUNT,
       CODE, 
       SUM(CONSIDERATION)  AS CONSIDERATION
FROM dbo.YourTable yt
GROUP BY [DATE],
        ACCOUNT,
        CODE
ORDER BY [Date],
        ACCOUNT,
        CODE
```